# use angularjs data binding in codeigniter view

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, codeigniter-2

I would like to use the ability of angularjs for data binding in one of my codeigniter view where inside of a form I make calculations between different input fields and I summarize this results in a table. I have to mention that I'm just in experiment phase with angularjs and I can really decide if this would be a good workaround. If angularjs is good decision what is the best way to implement data binding in a codeigniter view

Comment: not clear what you want since the two frameworks run in completely different environments

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with CodeIgniter but after looking at it briefly I would say that you understand angularjs a bit wrong. It is just completely client side however it ca use server side templates and server side controllers (by AJAX calling via $http). So angularjs bindings will not work in your CI views as they are server based while AngularJS views and bindings are client based.

One possible integration you can achieve if you still want to use CI functionality is writing some REST services and getting the necessary data (for ex. with calculations) and render it at the client side using templates with angularjs bindings.

Another way (which is sometimes used for Node.js applications) is using dynamic templates (getting the templates from the server side after server side processing). So in this case if you can combine the CI view with angularjs bindings you will update these views with the server side data and return these views as the templates to render the data at the clients side via bindings. Smth like a mix of two ways of putting and rendering the data.